# Can't get string numbers to become float or integer PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse a csv file with PHP and everything works ok as long as I keep the numbers as strings. However, since I'd like to sum the values of nested arrays I need them to be numbers.

There are three values that I need to fix:

- $column[1] is **cost** and contains decimals (ex. 20.30)
- $column[2] is **clicks** (ex. 15)
- $column[3] is **conversions** (ex. 3)

If I try using floatval() or intval() on the values they return 0.

Example: $cost = intval($column[1]);

I saw somewhere in another thread that they use trim() or ltrim() to clean up the value. So I tried that on my numbers...

- $cost = intval(trim($column[1]));
- $clicks = intval(trim($column[2]));
- $conversions = intval(trim($column[3]));

But that just gives me the first digit of the number, so I get this..

- **cost** : 2 (instead of 20.30)
- **clicks** : 1 (instead of 15)
- **conversions**: 3 (is actually correct)

I've tried using both "." and "," as decimals.

Really can't figure this one out. Any help I can get is much appreciated!

### Structure:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(21)"avslag l�n"[1]=> string(11)"31.32"[2]=> string(3)"1"[3]=> string(5)"0 "
}
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(45)"l�na trots kronofogden"[1]=> string(11)"99.12"[2]=> string(3)"2"[3]=> string(5)"0 "
}
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(59)"g�r gymnasiet men vill ta l�n"[1]=> string(11)"33.86"[2]=> string(3)"1"[3]=> string(5)"0 "
}
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(45)"l�n till enskild firma"[1]=> string(11)"80.07"[2]=> string(3)"1"[3]=> string(5)"1 "
}
```

Comment: Can you post the result of var_dump($column)?

Comment: Looks as though there may be some invisible characters (e.g. nulls) in your values... can you do a hex dump of a value?

Comment: lol ask and you shall receive.  You can edit your post and put that into code format by selecting it all and hitting `CTRL+K`

Comment: Given that `string(11) "33.86"` is 5 visible characters but a length of 11 bytes, then there are definitely invisible characters in the string... try doing a `str_replace("0x00",'',$value)` to strip out any `null` bytes.... doing a hex dump of a value would confirm the specifics of the invisible characters

Comment: How do I find and remove the hidden characters?

Comment: If those hidden characters are nulls, then the str_replace() I gave in my previous comment will remove them. It may also be that the file is using a dual-byte charset, in which case you could use iconv() or mb_convert_encoding() if you knew what charset it was

Answer (score 3):

You could type cast the values as follows:

```
$cost = (double) $column[1];
$clicks = (int) $column[2];
$conversions = (int) $column[3];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

if you are looking to format the double then do the following:

```
$cost = number_format($column[1], 2);
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for the var_dump, try this.

```
$cost = (double) $column[0][1];
$clicks = (int) $column[0][2];
$conversions = (int) $column[0][3];
```

You are trying to interact with a 2D array as if it was 1 dimensional.

Comment: yep.  I do this with a Drupal module and works great.

Comment: If I do that they all just becomes 0.

Comment: What does **var_dump($column[1]);** give you?

Comment: All the cost values as strings... string(11) "31.32"
string(11) "99.12"
string(11) "33.86"

Comment: You are trying to compute an entire column. You need to interact with the data as a 2D array. $column[0][1], etc. see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

use number format with floatval

```
$cost = floatval(column[1]);
$cost = number_format($cost, 2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Tried that too but that just gives me nothing ("").

Answer (score 1):

if value of `$column[1]` is `"20.30"` you can simply use it for calculations as php automatically converts string to numbers when you do arthritic calculations.
ex:

```
$column[1]="20.30";//$column[1] is string.
$column[1]*=1.0;//Now $column[1] is an float variable..
```

You can also use type conversion like:

```
$a=(float)$column[1]*1;
```

And so on..

Answer (score 1):

I *could* be wrong...in which case I have a gambling problem apparently...**but I'm fairly certain** you're trying to do all these conversions on an actual `array()`, not a `string`.

Your printout shows 4 different arrays, each with key/value pairs.  And all of these are linked into `$column`.

If I had to guess, which I shouldn't do on Stack Exchange, I would say try this:

```
$column[1][1]
```

instead of what you have now as

```
$column[1]
```

I've been up quite a long time though so grain of salts are to be taken here.

Comment: If typecasting is not working for him, this can be the only thing that could be causing the problems. :D Good job spotting that.

Comment: $column[1][1] actually gets me the first digit of the cost number.  So if I do $cost = $column[1][1] . $column[1][2] I get the 2 first digits :S

Comment: well, oddly enough that coincides with the actual first digits of [1] and [2] - [1] = "31.32" and [2] = "1" which will give 31 either way lol which is of course still odd since the only significance there is that only the first digits of both are being retrieved haha